# In Ant, how do I specify files with comma in filename?

Tags: java, python, ant, fileset, coverage.py

Here is an example-target that I tried.  Turns out, it wants to delete everything because the comma separates "****/*" and "cover" -- understandable.

```
<target name="clean">
    <delete
        verbose="true">
        <fileset dir="." includes="**/*.pyo"></fileset>
        <fileset dir="." includes="**/*,cover"></fileset>
    </delete>
</target>
```

How do I specify an embedded comma?

I'm trying to learn Ant so I won't have to maintain different build-systems for different operating-systems.  In this case, it's in a Python environment, where *,cover files are created by a code-coverage checking tool called [Coverage](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/).

Comment: Have you tried escaping it with a \ (backslash) character?

Comment: Yes, I did.  I also just tried Sheryl's suggestion with two backslashes, but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to escape this. Just use `<include/>` instead of `includes` arg. Try this:

```
<project name="test" default="clean">

    <dirname property="build.dir" file="${ant.file.test}" />

    <target name="clean">
        <delete>
            <fileset dir="${build.dir}/test">
                <include name="**/*,*.xml" />
            </fileset>
        </delete>
    </target>

</project>
```

By the way. You shouldn't use `.` (dot) in you `dir` argument. If you want to delete files in directory where you have got `build.xml` file you should pass absolute path (to do this you can use `<dirname/>` like in my example). If you will use `.` then you will have problems with nested build. Let's imageine that you have got two builds which delete files but first build also call second build:

maindir/build1.xml

```
<delete dir="." includes="**/*.txt" />
<!-- call clean target from build2.xml -->
<ant file="./subdir/build2.xml" target="clean"/>
```

maindir/subdir/build2.xml

```
<delete dir="." includes="**/*.txt" />
```

In this case build2.xml won't delete *.txt files in subdir but *.txt files in maindir because ant properties will be passed to build2.xml. Of course you can use `inheritAll="false"` to omit this but from my experience I know that using `.` in paths will bring you a lot of problems.

Comment: That worked!  `<fileset dir="."><include name="**/*,cover" /></fileset>` did the trick!  Good point about dir="." -- I will change it.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have other files with names that end in cover that you don't want to delete, just leave the comma out:

```
<fileset dir="." includes="**/*cover"></fileset>
```

If you do have other files that end in cover that you don't want deleted, try the backslash suggestion from MattDMo's comment.  You may have to double-backslash it ("`**/*\\,cover`").

Another possibility: Can you configure Coverage to put its output in another directory, so you can just delete the whole directory?  Or can you configure it to use a different output filename so you don't have this problem?  I'm not familiar with Coverage, but looking at the link you provided, it looks like the data_file option might do one or both of those things.

Comment: I took the comma out for now as an interim solution (two backslashes didn't seem to make any difference).  Thanks for the idea.